# MS Access - Data type mismatch - simple integer comparison

Tags: ms-access

I just cannot wrap my head around why I am getting this error?
"Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

```
SELECT * INTO Updated FROM (
SELECT a.*,
date() AS [Today],
DateValue([Last_Updated]) as [LastUpDateDate],
int(datediff("d", date(), DateValue([Last_Updated]))) as [mydatediff]
FROM Prior AS a 
 WHERE a.[Last_Updated] is not null
) t
WHERE t.[mydatediff] >= 1;
```

I just want a simple comparison of two integers and I keep getting the type mismatch error.

Comment: what type of data is [Last_updated]?

Comment: It is a date that is stored as Text.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that error. It works fine for me.

Comment: does the version matter?
Version 2208 (Build 15601.20456 Click-to-Run)

Comment: Is there another/better option to explicitly store the value returned from the datediff function as an integer?

Comment: Do a test of a query object with just the inner SELECT. I expect the DateDiff will return a negative value. The SELECT INTO syntax works for me but no records are saved because of the negative value. The table aliases and table qualifier prefixes are unnecessary.

Comment: DateValue will error if Last_Updated is Null. So does CDate(). If Null is possibility, need to deal with. `CDate(Nz(Last_Updated,Date()))`.

Comment: Also, I was getting an error for the Null in the Last_Updated, however I explicitly filtered those out and I stopped getting that error... so that isn't the issue.
      WHERE a.[Last_Updated] is not null

Comment: Yes, I know the comparison should be t.[mydatediff] >= -1 but it should run without a type mismatch error regardless.

Answer (score 0):

If `Last_Updated` is text, it probably holds some invalid date expressions.

Try using `IsDate` to filter those out:

```sql
SELECT * INTO Updated 
FROM 
(   SELECT 
        a.*,
        Date() AS [Today],
        DateValue([Last_Updated]) AS [LastUpDateDate],
        DateDiff("d", Date(), DateValue([Last_Updated])) AS [mydatediff]
    FROM 
        Prior AS a 
    WHERE 
        IsDate(a.[Last_Updated])
) t
WHERE 
    t.[mydatediff] >= 1;
```

Alternatively, filter the subquery:

```sql
SELECT 
  t.*, 
  Date() AS [Today], 
  DateValue(t.[Last_Updated]) AS [LastUpDateDate],
  DateDiff("d", Date(), DateValue(t.[Last_Updated])) AS [mydatediff]
INTO 
  Updated 
FROM 
( SELECT *
  FROM Prior
  WHERE IsDate([Last_Updated])
) t
WHERE 
  DateDiff("d", Date(), DateValue(t.[Last_Updated])) >= 1;
```

**Solution**

The trick is to force the subquery to finalise before retrieving its records. That can be done with `DISTINCT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Prior.Id, 
        DateValue([Last_Updated]) AS LastUpDateDate, 
        DateDiff("d",Date(),DateValue([Last_Updated])) AS mydatediff
    FROM 
        [Prior]
    WHERE 
        IsDate([Last_Updated]) <> False
)  AS T
WHERE T.mydatediff >= 1;
```

Sample:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: SELECT * INTO Updated 
FROM
(SELECT a.*, 
              Date() AS Today, 
              DateValue([Last_Updated]) AS LastUpDateDate, 
              DateDiff("d", Date(), DateValue([Last_Updated])) AS mydatediff
FROM Prior_RNV_Data AS a
WHERE IsDate(a.[Last_Updated])
        AND a.[Last_Updated] is not null
) t
WHERE t.[mydatediff] >= -1;

The inside works just fine.  Still getting the type mismatch error when I add the final
WHERE t.[mydatediff] >= -1

Comment: Try filtering the subquery; see extended answer, please.

Comment: In the (filter the subquery) version, access doesn't yet recognize t.[mydatediff].  I tried putting the logic to calculate that value in place of the new column name [mydatediff], but I just get the same Data type mismatch error.

Comment: `IsDate` will filter for valid date expressions only. But see edited answer, please.

Comment: Gustav, I appreciate the help.  I've tried the last query above.  As I mentioned before, Access doesn't recognize the column name [mydatediff] (the very last line of the code).  I tried substituting the DateDiff function which populates [mydatediff] but I still get the type mismatch error.

Comment: OK. Try the edit. Or something else is going on out of our sight.

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: You are right. Access is lazy and evaluated the data too late. Use `DISTINCT` to prevent that. See extended answer, please.

Comment: Yes!!!  That did the trick.  Thanks so much sticking with my on this one.